# JMETER Saving userIds in an array after JSon Extraction | within a Loop Controller

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to save extracted ids (with JSON Extractor) in an array of object.

Example of response :

```
  {
  "password": "galderma2022*",
  "userName": "5n",
  "firstName": "ykyrlkyfao",
  "userId": "qxoql",
}
```

For that I used JSR223 PostProcessor

```
Parameters= vars.get('UserIDs') ?:  []  

if (Parameters ) {Parameters= new   
groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(Parameters)}  

Parameters.add( "{'userId' : ${
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).userId} }")  

vars.put('UserIDs', 
new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(Parameters).prettyPrint())  

log.info("ids" + Parameters)  

log.info("UserIDs" + vars.get('param'))
```

The array of object will be used in another HTTP sampler.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWWoH.png)

I wanted the Array to contain objects

But it was like this

```
[
    "{userId : 759 }",
    "{userId : 757 }",
    "{userId : 758 }"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)
2. We're not able to help you without seeing your full (or at least partial) response data and the desired [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) format

In the time being I can only share a couple of generic references:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

So for those that have the same problem, I found a solution :

```
def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def ids= vars.getObject('UserIDs') ?:  []
if (ids ) {ids= new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(ids)}
def object = {"userId" new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).userId}
ids.add(object)
vars.put('UserIDs', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(ids).toPrettyString())
```